# Is saving files to RBS any different than usual Library?

Tags: remote-blob-storage

I have lot of libraries in a SharePoint project, where I work. I'm working on a separate tool (console application), that uses object model to push large amount of files into SharePoint libraries.

Now, my bosses want to change to Remote BLOB Storage (and RBS is new to me). Mostly because SQL server is choking on large amount of data (I'm pushing gigabytes of data and it takes hours). And now we're expecting, that it would greatly improve, when the data is written to super-fast disks instead of DB.

My question is - is saving files to RBS any different than normal SharePoint lists? This is excerpt of my code:

```
FileStream fileStream;
//get file from some network location
filestream = GetFileFromSomeNetworkLocation();

SPFile spFile = spWeb.GetFile(myLibraryPath);
spFile.SaveBinary(fileStream);
```

If there is now RBS, do I need make changes?

Comment: It's supposed to be transparent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, SharePoint will take care of that internally for you.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if not already enabled, you may want to enable BLOB Caching on the WFE servers. This will not improve upload performance, but it will help in downloads by storing frequently used data into the WFE servers memory (saving you a round trip to the DB).